# How to prove that $p$ is an Hermite polynomial?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, hermite-polynomials

**Problem:** Let $$H_n(x):=(-1)^n e ^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e ^{-\frac{x^2}{2}})$$ be the $n^{th}$-Hermite polynomial and $$G_n(t,x):=t^{\frac n 2}H_n(\frac {x}{\sqrt{t}})$$ Moreover, let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion. The problem is to show the following:

> if $p(t, x)$ is a polynomial such that $(p(t, B_t))_{t \geq 0}$ is a
> martingale then $p$ is an Hermite polynomial, i.e. there exists $n \in
>  \mathbb{N}$ with $p(t, x)= G_n(t,x)$.

**Attempt:** i know that in such a way the converse is true. I am referring to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068035/hermite-polynomial-with-brownian-motion-is-martingale). I have tried to retrace the proof in reverse but noting has come.

Comment: Any other conditions? Since any linear combination of $G_n(t,B_t)$ is still a martingale.

Comment: @czxvebiastjuslpgyqm your remark is correct, but I do not have any others conditions. Maybe there are some other requests but they have to be found.

Comment: I find something relevant.https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02362289?msclkid=22041ee9c22a11eca73ca83947299946

Comment: @czxvebiastjuslpgyqm thank you!